# Can I add my own pages to the Salesforce Chatter app? As you would for the Salesforce Touch App

Tags: chatter

I have been using Salesforce touch for sometime, and I am wondering if I can add projects to Salesforce Chatter in the same way.

So making a visual force page 'Available In Touch' probably isnt enough.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Well,  kinda.

With the newest versions of chatter, you can add chatter publisher actions. Those chatter publisher actions can have a VF bit. Start with http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm for more info.

Comment: Ive read some of the documentation and it seems as if this is more for individual objects, as opposed to full VF pages.

Thanks for the answer though!!

Comment: You can write chatter publisher actions for individual objects for all objects i believe. Additionally the actions can have associated vf pages.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can add publisher actions.

Actions have two types so far:

1) You can have a Chatter action that creates a record. This action will display a form with fields which are defined on a page layout (Works in iOS Chatter App). Unfortunately there is no update or delete chatter action yet, as far as I can tell.

2) You can have a chatter action that displays a custom Visualforce page (This does NOT work/display in the iOS Chatter App).

These actions can be defined in two contexts:

1) Object specific actions are essentially actions that allow you to use either of the types above to create records related to the current record, or to pull an info (i.e. an Id) from the current record into a custom Visualforce page (you have to include the Standard Controller of the record/object for these custom pages).

2) Global actions are just a simple way to fire off one of the two types with zero context, an example of this would be creating a brand new unrelated record.

In short, if you are looking for anything more than a simple record creation Chatter Action, I don't think chatter actions are very useful in the current iOS mobile app.

In the future, if the custom Visualforce actions are added, I would expect them to come in a new UIWebView that is essentially disconnected from the app. This somewhat neuters the effectiveness of the feature as you are just trapped inside of a frame and have no control over what the app will display when that frame is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do actions in the web-based chatter feed, but they aren't available in mobile app yet.  Winter 14 has settings for this (and for canvas!) so don't be surprised if it shows up in the next chatter mobile release once every production instance has moved to winter14.